# Error in translation filter gem activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using gem 'activeadmin'.

Sorting model appears a translation error, need help.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYnDP.png)

```
ActionView::Template::Error (translation missing: ru.ransack.predicates.equals):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a knowing issue in ActiveAdmin:

- https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3958
- https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3866

Currently the only way to fix this is to add this to your locale file:

```
ru.ransack.predicates.equals: "равна"
```